# How do I set camel case attributes in Dart Web UI?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I have a Dart Web UI class like this:

```
class PersonComponent extends WebComponent {
  bool loggedIn;
  String name;
}
```

and I'm using it like this:

```
<x-person loggedIn="{{loggedIn}}"></x-person>
```

However, when I run the app, I get a NoSuchMethodError, because it can't find `loggedin=`

How do I set a camel case attribute name in a Web UI class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that HTML attributes are always lowercase, so Dart Web UI will convert `loggedIn` to `loggedin`.

To use camel case, you must use `logged-in` as an attribute.

Here is an example:

```
<x-person logged-in="{{loggedIn}}"></x-person>
```